# Can't solve the selected radio button puzzle in recycler view to add the value of all items?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-radiobutton

I have added the radio buttons dynamically in the `RecyclerView`. Now I want to get the total price with the selected radio buttons of `RecyclerView`. Somehow I can't understand the puzzle.

[image: Snapshot]

Comment: did you get your answer?

Comment: I have solved that. @BlackBlind

Comment: can you please share an answer with me

Answer (score 0):

just checked first when u clicked on button then it is already clicked or not with this position if not then add your price and display total amount.
Like this

```
 clicked.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(clicked.isChecked()){
                       amountwithsecdepo = String.valueOf((model.no_of_days*model.charge_per_day)+(model.deposit_amount)+100);
                    setAnimation(getResources().getString(R.string.rs_sysmbol)+" "+String.valueOf(amountwithsecdepo));
                }else {
                    int temp = (orderModel.o_duration_days * model.charge_per_day) + 100;
                    setAnimation(getResources().getString(R.string.rs_sysmbol)+" "+String.valueOf(temp));
                }
            }
    });
```

Comment: Have you understood what is the problem? @Bpatel

Answer (score 0):

I think that this might solve your problem.
In your recycler adapter take a float/double variable which will store total. 
Initially it will be 0.

in your adapter setOnCheckedChangeListener on your radio button (Inside the ViewHolder Class which is inside your adapter (usually)).
Now whenever you will click on the radio button, the control will go to the checkChangeListener.

all you have to do is add total there.

```
if (isSelected) {
total = total + yourModel.get(getAdapterPosition()).getPrice();
} else {
total = total - yourModel.get(getAdapterPosition()).getPrice();
}
```

Let me know if its not clear to you.